# Exiting shell script if script throws error

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a curl command that kicks off to start OR stop a process.Script works as expected when i run it to start/stop the service, but it throws an exception when the process is already started and i try to start it again. how can i exit the gracefully?

Script:

```
x=$1
action=`echo "$x" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
y=$2
#echo "ID passed is $y"

echo $action"ing the process..."

curl -s -S -k -u user:pass -X PUT https://URL/$action || exit 1
```

If process is stopped/Started it works. Issue occurs when i try to start the process which is already in "Started" State.

USAGE: `./abc.sh start/stop 12345`

Error message is:

```
HTTP 409: Conflict

org.apache.juneau.rest.RestException: Action START cannot be performed for application instance TechDev2 &#40;fadc6b5c-782a-46a1-bf46-21f331f669c0&#41; because its state is STARTED.
        at com.platform.vem.gui.web.rest.EgoRestCallHandler.renderError(EgoRestCallHandler.java:60)
        at com.ibm.asc.ascd.core.rest.api.ConductorRestCallHandler.renderError(ConductorRestCallHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.juneau.rest.RestCallHandler.handleError(RestCallHandler.java:273)
        at org.apache.juneau.rest.RestCallHandler.service(RestCallHandler.java:189)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put few things in place that can help:

> Check the process is already running or not before starting it again.

Use `ps -ef|grep <process>`

> When you start/stop the process, retrieve the exit status with `$?`
>   and use it to design the flow.

Comment: It is not a unix process so i will not be able to grep it. I already tried $? and the output was 0 on both the occassions